# object detection using yolo and deep sort

Tags: python

```
def update(self, dets=np.empty((0, 6))):
        """
    Params:
      dets - a numpy array of detections in the format [[x1,y1,x2,y2,score, Class],[x1,y1,x2,y2,score, Class],...]
    Requires: this method must be called once for each frame even with empty detections (use np.empty((0, 6)) for frames without detections).
    Returns a similar array, where the last column is the object ID and the second-to-last column is the class label.

    NOTE: The number of objects returned may differ from the number of detections provided.
    """
        self.frame_count += 1
        # get predicted locations from existing trackers.
        trks = np.zeros((len(self.trackers), 6))
        to_del = []
        ret = []
        for t, trk in enumerate(trks):
            pos = self.trackers[t].predict()[0]
            trk[:] = [pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3], 0, 0]
            if np.any(np.isnan(pos)):
                to_del.append(t)
        trks = np.ma.compress_rows(np.ma.masked_invalid(trks))
        for t in reversed(to_del):
            self.trackers.pop(t)
        matched, unmatched_dets, unmatched_trks = associate_detections_to_trackers(dets, trks, self.iou_threshold)

        # update matched trackers with assigned detections
        for m in matched:
            self.trackers[m[1]].update(dets[m[0], :])

        # create and initialize new trackers for unmatched detections
        for i in unmatched_dets:
            # if i < dets.shape[0]:  # Check if i is a valid index for dets
            trk = KalmanBoxTracker(dets[i, :])
            self.trackers.append(trk)

        i = len(self.trackers)
        for trk in reversed(self.trackers):
            d = trk.get_state()[0]
            if (trk.time_since_update < 1) and (trk.hit_streak >= self.min_hits or self.frame_count <= self.min_hits):
                if i < dets.shape[0]:  # Check if i is a valid index for dets
                    ret.append(np.concatenate((d, [trk.id, dets[i, -1]])).reshape(1,-1))  # +1 as MOT benchmark requires positive
            i -= 1
            # remove dead tracklet
            if trk.time_since_update > self.max_age:
                self.trackers.pop(i)
        if len(ret) > 0:
            return np.concatenate(ret)
        return np.empty((0, 6))
```

I want to detect vehicles and classify them so far it is detecting and counting, but it sometimes misses, and does not count how can I solve this problem?